# How do I generate a matrix?

Tags: ruby, matrix

I have the following data:

```
gene strain
A1   S1
A1   S4
A1   S8
A2   S5
A2   S4
A2   S9
A3   S4
A3   S1
A3   S10
```

I need to produce a matrix that has the genes vs strains, I.E., I need to show which genes are present in which strains, so the matrix will look like this:

```
 S1 S4 S5 S8 S9 S10
A1   
A2
A3
```

Can anyone guide me through the best and quickest way to do this in Ruby?  I have the array of strains and genes.

Comment: Check [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class.

Comment: Are you expecting a matrix with binary entries (presence/absence)?

Comment: Yes i am expecting a matrix with binary entries (presence/absence)

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477874/is-there-a-database-or-a-data-structure-for-ruby-to-implement-relation-matrices) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could represent the gene-strain matrix you need. The best way will depend on what you want to do with the matrix. Do you want to compare which strains are present in different genes? Or compare which genes have a given strain? Do you just want to be able to look up whether a given gene has a given strain?

One simple way would be a `Hash` whose keys are `Set`s:

```
require 'set'
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Set.new }
# assuming you already have the data in an array of arrays...
data.each do |gene,strain|
  h[gene] << strain
end
```

If you only want to print a matrix out on the screen, here is a little script to do so:

```
require 'set'
genes, strains = Set.new, Set.new
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Set.new }
# again assuming you already have the data in an array of arrays
data.each { |g,s| h[g] << s; genes << g; strains << s }
genes, strains = genes.sort, strains.sort

FIELD_WIDTH = 5    
BLANK       = " "*FIELD_WIDTH
X           = "X" + (" " * (FIELD_WIDTH - 1))
def print_fixed_width(str)
  str = str[0,FIELD_WIDTH]
  print str
  print " "*(FIELD_WIDTH-str.length)
end

# now print the matrix
print BLANK
strains.each { |s| print_fixed_width(s) }
puts

genes.each do |g|
  print_fixed_width(g)
  strains.each { |s| h[g].include?(s) ? print X : print BLANK }
  puts
end
```

Please post more details on what you want to do with the matrix and I will provide a more appropriate option if necessary.

Comment: thanks. i need to check which genes are present in which strains

Comment: So will you need to take a given gene, and see which strains have it? Or will you need to take a given strain, and see which genes are present in it? Or both?

Comment: As a side note, if you plan on checking the gene -> strain membership on large amounts of data, I would consider using a hash instead of a Set to check for membership - it's [faster](https://gist.github.com/1827686) than both Set.include? and Array.include?. In @AlexD's code, that would translate to `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }` followed by `h[gene][strain] = true`. You could then test for membership simply by `h[gene][strain]` rather than `h[gene].include?(strain).`

Answer (score 0):

You can represent this in a 2d array:

```
arr = [[1,1],[1,4],[1,8],[2,5],[2,4],[2,9],[3,4],[3,1],[3,10]]
```

quick and dirty table:

```
s = "  1234567890\n"
(1..3).each do |i|
  s << i.to_s << ' '
  (1..10).each do |j|
    s << ( arr.include?( [i,j] ) ? 'x' : ' ' )
  end
  s << "\n"
end
puts s

  1234567890
1 x  x   x  
2    xx   x 
3 x  x     x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you " need to check which genes are present in which strains", then a Hash would be sufficient:

```
str = <<DOC
A1   S1
A1   S4
A1   S8
A2   S5
A2   S4
A2   S9
A3   S4
A3   S1
A3   S10
DOC

ar = str.lines.map{|line| line.split(/\s+/) } #string to array of arrays
genes_from_strain = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[] }  #This hash will give an empty array if key is not present
ar.each{|pair| genes_from_strain[pair.last] << pair.first }
p genes_from_strain['S1'] #=>["A1", "A3"]
```